# how to hide button in other view controller in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, xib

```
-(void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    NewsScreen *news=[[NewsScreen alloc] initWithNibName:@"NewsScreen" bundle:nil];

    if (tabBarController.selectedIndex==2) {

        [news.btn setHidden: YES];

    }
    NSLog(@"%@", tabBarController);
}
```

I want to hide button which is from the other view controller.

Comment: There are two issues to overcome. 1) How do you find a reference to the other view controller and call a method on it.  2) How do you hide a button.  Which of these is causing you a problem?

Comment: 2 one. But I want to hide a button of other view controller when I click on tabbarcontroller item

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    -(void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {

            if (tabBarController.selectedIndex==2) 
            {
              NSUInteger *index=value; //assign value here
              UINavigationController *nv = [[tabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:index];//index of your NewsScreen controller
              NSArray *array =[nv viewControllers];

              for (ViewController *vc in array)
              {
                if ([vc isKindOfClass:[NewScreen class]])
                {
                  [vc.btn setHidden:YES];
                }
              }

            }
            NSLog(@"%@", tabBarController);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

take a `BOOL` variable in your `ViewController` `controller` and make the property. and `synthesize` it also.

then do like this:

```
ViewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
vc.check = YES;
```

in  `viewdidload` write this:

```
if(self.check)
    [mainbutton1 set hidden:YES];
```

**Update**

if you want to just hide button then try like:

In your `Viewdidload`

```
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(btnClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

-(void)btnClicked
{
    [button setHidden:YES]; 
}
```

Comment: it is not taking (self.check)

Comment: I don't want it in view controller as well.

Comment: you want a certain button to be hidden if something has been happening somewhere else.... ryt?

Comment: or you just want.. when you click button... it hides.??

Comment: yes right. It if not accepting (Self.check) and even btn direct. It required news.btn

Comment: I just want it to hide.

Comment: I want to hide it an the click of item in tabbar delegate like this  if (tabBarController.selectedIndex==2) {

        [news.btn setHidden: YES];

    } but it is not working whyI dont know

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to:

```
-(void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {

    NewsScreen *news= (NewsScreen*) [tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1]; // Replace 1 with your NewsScree View Controller's index thats your tab number - 1.

    if (tabBarController.selectedIndex==2) {
        [news.btn setHidden: YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: showing error unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ff0ea657b00'

Comment: You didn't mentioned you are using Navigation Controller in each tab.
First fetch navigation controller from tabBarController.viewControllers and then check for NewsScreen's object in that Navigation Controller's viewControllers then perform action on it.